# Enabling File Geodatabase support in QGIS on OSX?

Tags: qgis, gdal, file-geodatabase, osx

What steps do I need to take to get Esri .gdb files functioning in QGIS?

I'm a QGIS user running v2.0 (Dufour) on Mac OSx 10.8.5.  I have some data in .gdb format and need to access this and work with it in QGIS.  I'm a relatively savvy computer user, but not at all a programmer or developer.  I've been reading the forums and have seen some steps outlined for GDAL installs etc., and compiling etc., but am a bit daunted and don't want to mess something up on my system.

Alternately I could try to use GDB Flee or something like it, but not sure where to start.

Comment: Artwork21's answer below will work if you have OGR's FGDB driver installed.  To check if you do, you can use the command line.  Change to the directory where your FGDB is stored, then use ogrinfo -so <directory name>.  For example if your FGDB is called gis_data the command to use is ogrinfo -so gis_data.gdb.  If you have the driver installed you'll get a list of the feature classes, if not it will tell you the dataset is not recognized.

Comment: @HeyOverThere, When I installed QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.0.1 (64bit), http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html,  the OGR's FGDB driver must be included because I did install this separately.

Comment: So, @HeyOverThere for a luddite, to access the command line in OSX I do what exactly?  Thanks!  I'm used to point & click navigating.  I tried to access it in terminal, but I get a message: "No such file or directory"

Comment: So @artwork21, if I just did the usual install of 2.0, I won't have the FGDB driver?

Comment: @KMT, I did the 2.0.1 install with no additional driver install (driver install is not required).

Comment: @artwork21 From your screenshot it looks like you're using Windows.  The Mac/Linux installs take a little hand holding to get FGDB support.

Comment: @KMT : The first thing to try is just type ogrinfo to see if it is installed and in your path.  If it gives you an error message that shows you the command's usage and tells you there is no data source specified you're good to go.  Use the command cd to change directories until you're in the same directory as your file geodatabase.  Then you can use the ogrinfo -so gis_data.gdb command, replacing gis_data with your FGDB's name.  If when you type ogrinfo it tells you command not found you'll need to install it.

Answer (score 3):

In the Add vector layer dialog select Directory radio button and you should see FGD as an option, see caption below:

[image]

Then just browse and select the .gdb directory through the browse window.  You will then see a list of the feature classes within which you can select to add to your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/)'s File Geodatabase [driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html) installed visit [KyngChaos's page](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).  Install the [GDAL 1.10 framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-1.10.dmg), then the [FGDB plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL-FileGDB_Plugin-1.10.1-1.dmg).  You'll need to download the [FDGB API](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3) from ESRI as well.  Once all those are installed you can install [QGIS](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).  Once QGIS is installed follow @artwork21's answer to actually access your data.  Then call up the data's provider and yell at them for distributing it in a non-free, patent encumbered data format.

Comment: @ HeyOverThere Ok - have downloaded all three, but having difficulty with the FGDB API - it's unzipped, but when I look for my Library (from Finder, command-shift-G and type ~/Library, right?), The Application Support Folder has no GDAL folder.  Ideas?  Also, if there's a space in a directory name, can Terminal follow that path? I'm thinking not as my current directory has a space and it's not reading the second word.  THanks!

Comment: @KMT - The easiest thing to do is copy the files you need to where they need to go.  When you unzipped the file, it created a FileGDB_API folder.  In that folder there are two import folders /include and /lib.  Copy the contents of include to /usr/local/include and the contents of /lib to /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Can't seem to find my /local folder.  Took a screenshot but not sure how to post here.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: @KMT check out this link for an overview of the OS X file system structure:  http://gotofritz.net/blog/tutorials/unix-osx-folder-hierarchy/

Comment: Ok!  Finally have the option to add a FileGDB, but get the error - "Invalid data source" and something about an urecognized file type.  Does this mean it was created in Arc9.x and isn't compatible?  Argh.

Comment: You can test with sample data that is packaged with the API.  In the folder you unzip there is directory called samples and in there is a directory called data.  In the data directory there are several FGDBs, if you can open those in QGIS then yes, most likely the databases you're trying to open are from an incompatible version.

Comment: Darn - looks like the sample data works, so my files aren't compatible.  So frustrating!  (shakes fist at ESRI).  Will try to find someone with Arc 10 to convert them.  Thanks so much @HeyOverThere for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not the best solution. But with a Mac running QGIS 2.0 it worked.

1. install GPS Babel, available both for Win or Mac
2. load the file Garmin gdb
3. convert/save as Garmin gpx
4. open on QGIS

It worked for me.

Comment: Garmin gbds are a *completely* different animal from Esri gdbs. The question's original wording and tags leave this open to confusion, so I suppose this answer might serve someone who stumbles across it. Typically Garmin files will be in the context of/with a GPS tag though.